# Cannot alter MySQL function due to DEFINER error after change of IP Address

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

I have a MySQL db that I connect to via SQLYog. When I connect, my home IP address is appended to my username. For example: xxxx_ratesadmin@123.456.789

This creates the definer of an object such as a stored procedure or function and I can only alter those objects when connecting from that IP address.

Some time ago I was forced to switch ISP and was provided with a new IP address before this happened I took a back up of the database so I would be able to change the definer to the new IP but I missed a number of Stored Procedures and functions which I now need to alter but can't and just get the error "Unable to retrieve information. Please check your permission." I also cannot access them through phpmyadmin as there is no edit button next to those objects.

I thought I might be able to do this through the routines table in information_schema but apparently don't have permissions to make changes to that and there is no edit option when viewing that table in phpmyadmin.

This would not be so bad if I could at least copy the contents of the routine so I could recreate the objects but they just show as blank fields for any object with the old definer.

If anyone can give me any guidance on this it would be hugely appreciated! :)

Kind Regards

Mike

Answer (score 0):

This has now been resolved. I spoke to my hosting company who were able to login with the main root account and change the definer on all objects for me. Should have done that in the first place really!